# Rails 3: Error when running a simple test using RailsGuides instructions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to run a simple test following [RailsGuides instructions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#running-tests). I have a default structure of the `test` folder. Here is the relevant part:

```
test
  unit
    job_test.rb
  test_helper.rb
```

When I run:

```
ruby unit/job_test.rb
```

from the `test` directory, I get:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': 
    no such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from unit/job_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Here is my `job_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'
class JobTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "My First Test" do
    assert false
  end
end
```

Is this a known Rails 3 issue ?

Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to include test helper like this

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Another solution is to run `ruby -I test test/unit/job_test.rb` from the application directory. I still wonder why the generated code by Rails doesn't work?!